# Rounded Corner of RichTextBox in wpf

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, richtextbox, rounded-corners

It is possible to make RichTextBox have corner radius in wpf. i know it can achive using ControlTemplate but how?

I hope some of you may provide me with a hint.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about putting a border around it?

```
 <Border BorderThickness="2" CornerRadius="6">
 <your:RichTextBox />
 </Border>
```

Comment: if the developer of richtextbox has no border corner radius developed, you need to do it yourselfe. I agree to Klaus.

Answer (score 3):

Just add a style:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type RichTextBox}">
    <Style.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
            <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="5" />
        </Style>
    </Style.Resources>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 2):

I've tried Klau's suggestion, and it didn't work for me, so I came with a little bit of something on my own:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="TextBoxBorder" EndPoint="0,20" MappingMode="Absolute" StartPoint="0,0">
        <GradientStop Color="#ABADB3" Offset="0.05"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#E2E3EA" Offset="0.07"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#E3E9EF" Offset="1"/>
    </LinearGradientBrush>
    <Style x:Key="{x:Type TextBoxBase}" BasedOn="{x:Null}" TargetType="{x:Type TextBoxBase}">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowBrushKey}}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource TextBoxBorder}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="AllowDrop" Value="true"/>
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.PanningMode" Value="VerticalFirst"/>
        <Setter Property="Stylus.IsFlicksEnabled" Value="False"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBoxBase}">
                    <Border x:Name="Bd" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"  SnapsToDevicePixels="true" CornerRadius="20" BorderThickness="9,6,10,7">
                        <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}}"/>
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="{x:Type Hyperlink}" TargetType="{x:Type Hyperlink}">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Blue"/>
        <Setter Property="TextDecorations" Value="Underline"/>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="RichTextBoxWithRoundedCorners" TargetType="{x:Type RichTextBox}">
        <Style.Resources>
            <Style x:Key="{x:Type FlowDocument}" TargetType="{x:Type FlowDocument}">
                <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
            </Style>
            <Style x:Key="{x:Type Hyperlink}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Hyperlink}}" TargetType="{x:Type Hyperlink}">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Blue"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Style.Resources>
        <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="10"/>
        <Style.BasedOn>
            <StaticResource ResourceKey="{x:Type TextBoxBase}"/>
        </Style.BasedOn>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

I've replaced the RichTextBoxe's default border with Border class, and this time it works:

```
<RichTextBox Background="White" Margin="75,0,114,94" Height="125" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Style="{StaticResource RichTextBoxWithRoundedCorners}"  />
```

And the picture:

[image: RichTextBox with rounded corners]

You probably can make this better, but this is a good start